# How to make payment using QR code in WeChat?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, wechat, wechat-auth, wechat-official-account

Hi I have WeChat API's and I am trying to make payment with code_url got from the unified order API result.

I got code_url from unified order result, and I converted it to QR code image and scanned that QR code to make a payment, but when I scan QR code I get an error from the app saying "customers who is not verified by identity card are temporarily unable to pay abroad"

Can you please help with this?
Or is there another development source where I can test my payment with QR code

sample code_url is :

```
weixin://wxpay/bizpayurl?pr=YJDvtgp
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by your scanner wechat account, you have to :

1. verify the current wechat account by identity card(you have to be chinese citizen);
2. switch to another wechat account or let someone else to help.